# Show that there exists a unique ring homomorphism such that

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-homomorphism

Hi my question is as follows:

Let *A* be a domain, and let $A[T]$ be the ring polynomials over A.

Show that for any elements $a,b{\in}A$, there exists a unique ring homomorphism ${\varphi}_{a,b}:A[T]{\to}A[T]$ such that:

**(i)** ${\varphi}_{a,b}(T)=aT+b$ in $A[T]$ and

**(ii)** ${\varphi}_{a,b}$ induces the identity map on $A$.

I have thought of using the universal property of polynomials ring by first invoking a ring homomorphism ${\varphi}:A{\to}A[T]$ but this is where I am stuck. I have no idea how to idea how to construct such a map ${\varphi}$ that will allow me to have map ${\varphi}_{a,b}$ satisfying the mentioned hypothesis.

Any hints/help would be welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Observe that (i) and (ii) define a homomorphism. Why is it unique?

Comment: Am i right to say that because it is uniquely determined by coefficients a and b?

Comment: Yes. Do you know why (i) and (ii) determine a homomorphism and why it is welldefined?

Comment: From what I understand is that this map sends a polynomial p(T) to a scaled factor of T to p(aT+b). Then from here one can easily show that it satisfies the conditions of being a ring homomorphism and is welldefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ring homomorphism is an $A$-algebra homomorphism from $A[T]$ to itself. Now for any  $A$-algebra $B$, an algebra homomorphism from $A[T]$ to $B$ is uniquely determined by the image of the indeterminate $T$ in $B$. In other words:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}\Hom_{A\text{-alg}}(A[T],B)\simeq B,$$
and more  generally, for any set $I$
$$\Hom_{A\text{-alg}}(A[T_i]_{i\in I},B)\simeq B^I$$
($\simeq\;$ denotes here a bijection).